# Why am i getting segmentation fault in this code ?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to do this problem on hackerrank : 

 https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/funny-string/copy-from/17051736 
The size of the input string is supposed to vary from 1 to 10,000 but when i submit this code , it shows segmentation fault in test cases #7,8 and 9 . 
But when i use char array datatype instead of string datatype with the logic being the same , all the test cases are passed without problem . 
Why is this happening ? Shouldn't string datatype be able to store 10,000 characters just fine ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string S,R;
int T,i,j,flag,size;
cin>>T;
cin.ignore();
while(T--)
{
    cin>>S;
    for(i=S.size()-1,j=0;i>=0;--i,++j)
        R[j]=S[i];
    size=S.size();
    for(i=1,flag=1;i<size;++i)
    {
        if( abs(S[i]-S[i-1]) != abs(R[i]-R[i-1]) ) 
        {
            flag=0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1)
        cout<<"Funny"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Not Funny"<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
for(i=S.size()-1,j=0;i>=0;--i,++j)
    R[j]=S[i];
```

`R[j]` is not valid for any `j` since `R` has a zero size.

If you want `R` to be the reverse of `S` then you can just use

```
std::string R(S.rbegin(), s.rend());
//or
R.assign(S.rbegin(), s.rend());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not comment as a newbie:
Why not index S from the end as a fast way to get R?
Compare S[i-1] - S[i] with S[n-i] - S[n-i-1]
With n being the length. Just need to figure out the middle for the loop to end else you end up with double the max comparisons.